# Javascript change image and reset page unpon finish

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a "race" between two images. They start on the left, when I click on the third image it starts the race, when one makes it to the right side it stops them. And alerts the winner. Two things I can't get to happen... The image I click on wont change to a different image. And after the "race" is over, when I click on the image again, it wont reset everything and start over like new. I just continues whatever the random number is. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y71kpg1o/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <title>The Amazing Race</title>
</head>

<body>
   <img src="images/tie.png" class="img1" id="Stewie" alt="tie"></br>
   <img src="images/xwing.png" class="img2" id="Squidward" alt="xwing">
   <input type="image" src="images/death.png" class="img3" alt="dstar" onclick="interval = setInterval( fly, 250 )">




<script>
var racers   = [ document.getElementById("Cartman"), document.getElementById("Stewie") ];

function fly() {
var racer  = racers[ Math.floor(Math.random() * racers.length) ];
var newPos = parseInt( racer.style.left || 0 ) + 25;
racer.style.left = newPos + "px";
if( (newPos + racer.clientWidth) >= window.innerWidth){
    clearInterval( interval );
    alert( "And the winner is " + racer.id );
}    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, I have a CSS to place the images and size them. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: please create a fiddle - http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @jacelysh that you should provide a fiddle for a question like this, the answer is most likely obvious enough that it doesn't matter too much.

You are looking for

```
[ document.getElementById("Cartman"), document.getElementById("Stewie") ]
```

But your div ids suggest that you should be looking for

```
[ document.getElementById("Squidward"), document.getElementById("Stewie") ]
```

• To change the image of the one clicked you just need to update it's src property

There are a hundred ways to make the game reset when complete, but first off 
•  I'd wrap it in a function like endRace().
•  There you could add a class to the container which the child elements can use to reset themselves.

• As a side note you should try to get in the habit of moving your javascript out of the dom.  So listening for clicks in the javascript as opposed to onclick handlers in the dom.

I had nothing to do so I gave the fiddle a little overhaul which illustrates what I'm talking about.
http://jsfiddle.net/ryanore/y71kpg1o/1/

Comment: it is Squidward, I just copied and pasted when it use to be Cartman. my bad

Comment: sweet, glad I could help.  You should mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Wasn't really the answer I was looking for. I already had that ok, just posted the wrong name in the code. What I need help with is, to get the image to change color when clicked on, and when its clicked again it reloads the page.